# ModuleNotFOundError: No module named 'numpy.ma'; 'numpy' is not a package

Tags: windows, numpy, windows-10, python-3.6

I have installed Numpy 1.13.0 on Windows 10; however, when I try to execute the following code, it gives the above error

```
#!C:\Users\sukhpreet.singh\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp 
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
print(a.dtype)
```

Following are the details of error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "numpyy.py", line 4, in <module>
import numpy as np
File "C:\Users\sukhpreet.singh\Project\numpy.py", line 5, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
File "C:\Users\sukhpreet.singh\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_label
File "C:\Users\sukhpreet.singh\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 33, in <module>
import numpy.ma as ma
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.ma'; 'numpy' is not a package
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have a module called `numpy` on python's search path (at `C:\Users\sukhpreet.singh\Project\numpy.py`).

Unsurprisingly, when `matplotlib` tries to import `numpy.ma` it is finding **your** `numpy` module, not the library package.

**Conclusion:** Don't name your modules the same as other packages/libraries you'd like to use.